# Can't get certain data from JSON, returns undefined Angular 6

Tags: json, angular, typescript, observable

I'm trying to extract "data" from this JSON but it keeps throwing undefined as result.

**Extract of code where I'm getting this error:**

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.testService.getTestWithObservable().subscribe(
        res => {
            let user = res["users"];
            let user_data = user["data"];

            this.user_data = user_data;

            console.log(user_data);
            console.log(res);
        }
    );
}
```

res outputs the whole JSON but user_data throws:

ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined
    at SafeSubscriber._next

**JSON**

```
[{
    "id": 1,
    "users": {
        "user_id": 14,
        "data": [{
            "name": "James",
            "age": 20
        },
        {
            "name": "Damien",
            "age": 25
        }]
    }
}
{
    "id": 2,
    "users": {
        "user_id": 11,
        "data": [{
            "name": "James",
            "age": 20
        },
        {
            "name": "Damien",
            "age": 25
        }]
    }
}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result is array so you have to use index to access to the array data ,

```
    this.testService.getTestWithObservable()
     .map( result => result.map( i => i.users.data) )  // array of data array
     .subscribe(
        res => {

            this.user_data = [];
            res.forEach(i => this.user_data(...i));
            console.log(this.user_data); // all users data as array 
        }
    );
}
```

loop throw the data by ngFor

```
<div *ngFor="let user of user_data">
  {{user.name}} , age : {{user.age}}
</div>
```

Comment: How can I store "data" from both user 1 and 2 to use it later in a ngFor? Or should I iterate through the result directly?

Comment: the result is array so you can use it with ngFor

Comment: I can write an example if you want ??

Comment: That would be great, I'm not sure how to iterate through the array with ngFor yet

Comment: @prevox I have update the answer first I map the data to user data only so the resull is array of data array at the end I cobine all the data a single item array

Comment: Any idea of why I'm getting this after applying your code? TypeError: _this.user_data.apply is not a function

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON is an array so you need to use an index or a loop to access one of your item like this:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.testService.getTestWithObservable()
        .subscribe(
            res => res.forEach(user => this.user_data = [...(this.user_data || []), user['users']['data']]);
        );
}
```

Or:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.testService.getTestWithObservable()
        .subscribe(
            res => this.user_data = res[0]['users']['data']);
        );
}
```

The first code will store in the `user_data` array all the `data` prop of each users

Comment: Hello, I'm getting this: ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'concat' of undefined

Comment: Very interesting solution. Got another question, if you don't mind. After ngOnInit I got an array containing data to fill my table of users. I don't understand how to fill this array with the mapped result from the observable since I can't apply any logic outside of a function and if I write a function then call it on the same TS file I get "Function implementation is missing or not immediately following the declaration". Do you know why I get this?

Comment: @prevox > Can you ask a new question for your problem? Thank you